# Very different eigenvalues with different correlation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, regression, linear-regression

I don't understand the following problem: I simulated two data sets that differ in the sign of the correlation matrix, like this:

Programming language is R.

```
data_neg <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=500, mu=rep(0,2), Sigma=cbind(c(1, -0.9), c(-0.9, 1))))
```

```
data_pos <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=500, mu=rep(0,2), Sigma=cbind(c(1, 0.9), c(0.9, 1))))
```

When I calculate the following eigenvalues I get similiar results.

```
eigen(t(as.matrix(cbind(1, data_neg)))%*%as.matrix(cbind(1, data_neg)))$values
```

```
eigen(t(as.matrix(cbind(1, data_pos)))%*%as.matrix(cbind(1, data_pos)))$values
```

When I do this with 4x4 correlation matrix and different sign, I also get similiar eigenvalues.

BUT when I do it with a 3x3 correlation matrix like this:

```
data_neg2 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=500, mu=rep(0,3), Sigma=cbind(c(1, -0.5, -0.5), c(-0.5, 1, -0.5),c(-0.5, -0.5, 1))))
```

```
data_pos2 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n=500, mu=rep(0,3), Sigma=cbind(c(1, 0.5, 0.5), c(0.5, 1, 0.5),c(0.5, 0.5, 1))))
```

and calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix as above

```
eigen(t(as.matrix(cbind(1, data_neg2)))%*%as.matrix(cbind(1, data_neg2)))$values
```

```
eigen(t(as.matrix(cbind(1, data_pos2)))%*%as.matrix(cbind(1, data_pos2)))$values
```

I get for the data_neg2 following eigenvalues:

```
7.680168e+03, 7.370440e+03, 4.993057e+03, 1.455192e-11
```

and for data_pos2:

```
9518.989, 4991.912, 2598.929, 2580.389
```

which is totally different although I only changed the sign.

With the 2x2 and 4x4 matrix the change in the sign at the correlation matrix had no effect. Why is there this big difference with this 3x3 matrix?

Comment: You have chosen to present your "modus operandi" in a certain syntax **which doesn't help to follow you**. You should at least say which software environment you use.

Comment: sorry, I added this information. I use R

Comment: The only thing I am able to observe in this "jungle" is that in $7.680168e+03, 7.370440e+03, 4.993057e+03, 1.455192e-11$, your 3 first eigenvalues are of the same order of magnitude whereas the fourth eigenvalue is $0$, meaning that there are your fourth "data" is  a linear combination of your first three "data"...

Comment: Mh, but why is there not the same observation when simulating with the same correlation with positive signs? With 2x2 and 4x4 matrices there was no difference between the sign in correlation.

Comment: I am not able to say more because "data.frame(mvrnorm(", "cbind(" and all the like completely obscure what are the 2 x 2 and 4 x 4 matrices your are speaking about ... Reduce your question to the essential information and you surely will have answers...